# Getting the max/mode of groupby.size() results

Tags: pandas

I have a dataset containing "**Season - League name - home team winner**"
[image: Original Dataset]

I want to get **the most winning team in each league separately every season**; So I did a **group by** and applied the **size** function and got this dataset which have **the number of each teams home wins per league per season**.

[image: Group by dataset]

When I did apply the max function, I managed to get the number of home wins for the most winning team per season per league indeed

[image: max winning team]

However, I want to fetch the name of the team with the most wins per season per league, not its number of wins.

Any smarter, different way to address this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_max(g):
    g.count().sort_values(by='count', ascending =False).loc[0,:]

Groupby().apply(get_max)
```